# Java Web Application can't connect database on remote Tomcat 8 Server

Tags: java, mysql, sql, spring, tomcat

I have a Spring web application and I deployed this application in a remote Tomcat 8 server (AWS). I also deployed a database as an SQL file in the **same** server. When I tried to open my application in a web browser, the webpages were opened successfully but the web services doesn't work. I think it was because the web services uses the database.

This is my `database.properties`:

```
 jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/srfms
 jdbc.username=*****
 jdbc.password=*****
```

I also tried another configuration:

```
 jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://94.73.145.205:3306/srfms
 jdbc.username=*****
 jdbc.password=*****
```

I can connect this database wtth MySQL Workbench successfully.

Comment: can you provide the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if the driver for mysql is installed before you proceed, do not forget to copy the JDBC Driver's jar into `$CATALINA_HOME/lib.`

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked your VPC your database and application should be in same VPC. Also please check the IMRole and security group for DB.